# Winforms Await function does not throw Threading Exception when setting main thread property

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, async-await

I am transferring a clock control that was running synchronously to an async thread in order to improve performance.  I am new to async/await, but am very familiar with the "old" method (Thread/Threadstart/InvokeRequired/Begininvoke)...

I was expecting this to immediately throw an error, and have to add in a callback, etc.. But everything is running without error.  My question is, is this ok, or could this potentially encounter threading errors?

I basically just moved the entire function into a new function, and called it with an async call in the original function.  Original function was exactly the "GetTimeAsync()" one.

Main Thread property is called "AtomicTime" ... It *does* await return before hitting the "Dim s as String = """ call - so it does look like it is behaving properly, I am just confused as to why it's not throwing a cross thread error.  Is this handled "behind the scenes" now or something?

I looked through numerous threads trying to find an answer - my apologies if I missed one.  As you can imagine, search results bring up a multitude of issues spanning numerous actual errors.  It's possible this has already been answered, and I simply missed it.

```
Private Async Sub GetTime()
    Await Task.Run(Sub() GetTimeAsync())
    Dim s As String = ""
End Sub

Private Sub GetTimeAsync()
    Try
        Dim ntpServer As String = "wwv.nist.gov"
        Dim ntpData(47) As Byte
        ntpData(0) = &H1B
        Dim serverReplayTime As Byte = Convert.ToByte(40)

        Dim addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList
        Dim EndP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), 123)
        Dim soc As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
          SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
        soc.ReceiveTimeout = 3000
        soc.Connect(EndP)
        soc.Send(ntpData)
        soc.Receive(ntpData)

        soc.Close()
        soc.Dispose()
        Dim intPart As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplayTime)
        Dim fractPart As UInt32 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ntpData, serverReplayTime + 4)
        intPart = SwapEndianness(intPart)
        fractPart = SwapEndianness(fractPart)
        Dim mills As Object = (intPart * 1000) + ((fractPart * 1000) / &H100000000L)

        Dim networkDateTime As Object = (New DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).AddMilliseconds(mills)
        Dim localTime As DateTime = networkDateTime.ToLocalTime()
        AtomicTime = localTime '***HERE*** This works... Should it????
        addresses = Nothing
        EndP = Nothing
        networkDateTime = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim s As String = ex.ToString()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This is THE point of the async framework!

Comment: Sorry, let me expand. With a little more research you will find that what is happening is when you compile your code, the compiler is actually doing all that stuff for you by creating thread and stub and blah blah blah. By using the async awaiters, you don't have to do all that yourself, but instead can focus on the code like you always have.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  That is pretty awesome.  I guess it just seemed too simple or something.

Comment: @Steve However, unless I am missing something, the `GetTimeAsync` method is not actually async, and will be running in another thread because of the `Task.Run(Sub() GetTimeAsync())`.  However, since it looks like `AtomicTime` is just a `DateTime` property and not a UI component, there are no cross-thread issues anyway.

Comment: @Aaron What is the `AtomicTime` property?  Does it access the UI?  If not, I don't believe you will ever get any cross-thread exceptions.  Also, since `GetTimeAsync` is doing network IO, you may be better off using the async methods on `Socket` (`ConnectAsync`, `SendAsync`, `ReceiveAsync`) and `Dns` (`GetHostEntryAsync`) and making it an `Async` method, instead of using `Task.Run`.  From my understanding, which is admittedly limited, that would be the more typical usage of `Async`/`Await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties do not have a thread affiliation. So a "main thread property" doesn't make sense.

What you're probably thinking of is the cross-thread `InvalidOperationException` that happens when accessing UI object instances from a non-UI thread. Since in this case, `AtomicTime` is not a UI object, it can't have UI affinity. Now, if you were trying to update a label or something, then that would have UI affinity and you would get the exception.

The ideal way to do this asynchronously is to use a truly asynchronous API, not `Task.Run`. `Task.Run` is fine (for UI apps only) if you have CPU-bound work to do or only have a synchronous API available, but it's more of a fallback, use-it-if-you-have-to kind of solution. Pure asynchronous code is better.

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I will review your blog, and also check out the socket async methods provided by default.  I was talking about a cross thread exception - I mentioned it in paragraph 4: "...why it's not throwing a cross thread exception."  Your assumption was correct, however, I was speaking about this, and I see now why it would not impact the operation - thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as the solution, since it actually covers the original question in the thread.  My answer shows a solution, but it is more specific to sockets, so I felt yours was more applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I went with Mark's suggestion from main thread comments - using provided socket async functions.  This took a *little* more research, so I'm going to post the code (also, comments welcome.. This is completely from code examples I found online, but it is working - so I'm calling this one resolved, even though it's not technically using async/await functions/operators, it is using the built ins, which is probably preferable when available.

First, we need a connect, send, and receive event to hook up to for callbacks - these are going to be form-level variables.

```
 Public Class YourClass
     Private ConnectDoneEvent As System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
     Private SendDoneEvent As System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
     Private ReceiveDoneEvent As System.Threading.ManualResetEvent
     '...
 End Class
```

Don't forget to initialize to avoid null reference exceptions.  They take a boolean on initialization as to whether the block is set or not.  You probably want it unset/false, but verify that so you don't block a thread immediately on program start.

Next, we need to initiate the connect, wait on it, once it comes back, initiate the send, wait...receive.  I felt this was one of the coolest parts about this experience - this is super simple...  We have 3 functions to make, for callbacks on each event (connect, send, receive). They are pretty much identical:

```
Private Sub ConnectCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim soc As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        soc.EndConnect(ar)
        ConnectDoneEvent.Set()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub SendCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim soc As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        Dim iBytesSent As Integer = soc.EndSend(ar)
        SendDoneEvent.Set()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub ReceiveCallback(ar As IAsyncResult)
    Try
        Dim soc As Socket = CType(ar.AsyncState, Socket)
        Dim iBytesRcvd As Integer = soc.EndReceive(ar)
        ReceiveDoneEvent.Set()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try   
End Sub
```

Now, all we need to do is make the calls.  This is pretty straightforward

```
Dim ntpServer As String = "wwv.nist.gov"
Dim ntpData(47) As Byte
ntpData(0) = &H1B
Dim serverReplayTime As Byte = Convert.ToByte(40)
Dim addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(ntpServer).AddressList
Dim EndP As IPEndPoint = New IPEndPoint(addresses(0), 123)
Dim soc As Socket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
          SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp)
soc.ReceiveTimeout = 3000
soc.BeginConnect(EndP, AddressOf ConnectCallback, soc)
ConnectDoneEvent.WaitOne()
soc.BeginSend(ntpData, 0, ntpData.Length, SocketFlags.None, AddressOf SendCallback, soc)
SendDoneEvent.WaitOne()
soc.BeginReceive(ntpData, 0, ntpData.Length, SocketFlags.None, AddressOf ReceiveCallback, soc)
ReceiveDoneEvent.WaitOne()
soc.Close()
soc.Dispose()
```

Error handling excluded.  Make sure to include it in production versions.